# focus() does not seem to work after onblur()

Tags: javascript

I have a list of input fields and when I tab through them I want to loop back to the first one, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my HTML

```
<form id="form">
  <input id="mon" type="text"/> Month<br>
  <input id="day" type="text"/> Day<br>
  <input id="num" type="text"/> Year<br>
  <input id="amt" type="text"/> Amount<br>
</form>
```

and my javascript

```
window.onload=function(){
  $('mon').focus();
  $('amt').onblur=function(){
    //Process the input fields
    $('mon').focus();
  }
}
function $(a){return document.getElementById(a)}
```

Comment: Don't you need some # signs in your ID selectors?

Comment: @sethobrien - It's not jQuery... look at the `$` function defined in the question.

Comment: My bad. I set up what you're describing here in the SO page using the console, and it seemed to be fine for focusing the search box when I tabbed out of the answer box. Could you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `onblur` event handler is being called before the default handler, causing focus to shift first to input 'mon', then to whatever the browser thinks should be in focus next. Try using the `onkeypress` event. e.g.

```
window.onload=function(){
  $('mon').focus();
  $('amt').onkeydown = function(e) {
    //check for IE weirdness
    if (e === undefined && event !== undefined)
      e = event;
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      $('mon').focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
function $(a){return document.getElementById(a)}
```

Edit: `onkeydown` actually seems to work in more browsers

Edit 2: added IE case. IE doesn't always pass the event as an argument

Comment: I was hoping for an answer a little more elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the cursor to appear on the first input box, you need to assign the value of the input box to itself (hack). Also you need to "return false" to stop the event propagation. The modified blur function is below,

```
<input id="mon" type="text" onfocus="this.value=this.value;" />

$('amt').onblur = function(){ $('mon').focus(); return false; }
```

Comment: What browser did you test this in? It does not work for me in Firefox 7 or Chromium 13.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. I think this is what you want to achieve.
http://jsfiddle.net/CucuIonel/7Fpu3/7/

Comment: In Firefox 7, this does not quite work. The Month input box will be highlighted after tabbing out of the Amount box, but you cannot type in it.